# Discord.py rank command

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

```
{
    "341522422836625408-679072765583556720": {
        "experience": 111157,
        "level": 34,
        "last_message": 1590382008.6055543
    },
    "692075200690520184-679072765583556720": {
        "experience": 51,
        "level": 3,
        "last_message": 1590373878.9466648
    },
    "465887722721116162-679072765583556720": {
        "experience": 34,
        "level": 2,
        "last_message": 1590380700.2158434
    },
    "477106559676317717-679072765583556720": {
        "experience": 350,
        "level": 5,
        "last_message": 1590331947.6997736
    },
    "377116068994482176-679072765583556720": {
        "experience": 20,
        "level": 2,
        "last_message": 1590329384.397424
    },
}
```

Above is the input data which I will be using to make a command where it shows the top 3 users who had the most experience one the server. I have already made a command which gives user exp for typing. For now, the code is:

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        user = json.load(f)
    guild = str(ctx.guild.id)
    users = str(ctx.author.id)
    order = {k: v for k, v in sorted(user.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['experience'], reverse=True)}
    await ctx.send(order[str(users + "-" + guild): "experience"])
```

The current output is

**('', {'experience': experience_count, 'level': level_count, 'last_message': last_message_id})**

> user.id, guild.id, experience_count, level_count and last_message_id are different numbers.

If anyone can help me with the command that would be great! I am a beginner with python, so the code might be a bit messy or stupid. If you have any questions please ask me!

Comment: what do you meany by "user.id, guild.id, experience_count, etc"  different numbers and also add the expected output

Comment: for example, ('524434170764722178-679072765583556720', {'experience': 343, 'level': 5, 'last_message': 1590381887.0841906})

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: After I changed sorted(list(users.items()), key=lambda x: x[1]["experience"], reverse=True), the error log shows that there's a keyerror for ctx.send: 1

Comment: try this `sorted(user.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['experience'],  reverse=True)`. there is no need to convert `user.items()` to list.

Comment: The output was ('341522422836625408-679072765583556720', {'experience': 111483, 'level': 34, 'last_message': 1590384561.0857296}) when I tried `sorted(user.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['experience'], reverse=True)`

Comment: I also tried this:
`await ctx.send(order[str(users + "-" + guild): "experience"])`

Comment: but the users data you posted doesn't contain `experience': 111483`.

Comment: @komatiraju032 edited. The result seems to be the same as original. The code which I edited is the one you first asked me to change

Comment: check this output for the data you posted https://pastebin.com/V6sY3chi

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
data = {
    "341522422836625408": {
        "experience": 111157,
        "level": 34,
        "last_message": 1590382008.6055543
    },
    "692075200690520184": {
        "experience": 51,
        "level": 3,
        "last_message": 1590373878.9466648
    },
    "465887722721116162": {
        "experience": 34,
        "level": 2,
        "last_message": 1590380700.2158434
    },
    "477106559676317717": {
        "experience": 350,
        "level": 5,
        "last_message": 1590331947.6997736
    },
    "377116068994482176": {
        "experience": 20,
        "level": 2,
        "last_message": 1590329384.397424
    },
}


class ExperienceCount:

    def __init__(self, user, experience):
        self.user = user
        self.experience = experience

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<@{self.user}> has {self.experience} experience'


def get_top_experience(data):
    users = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        users.append(ExperienceCount(k, v['experience']))
    return sorted(users, key=lambda x: x.experience, reverse=True)

a = get_top_experience(data)
```

(`<@USER_ID>` @mentions the user)

You can incorporate this into a command.

```py
@client.command
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    leaderboard = get_top_experience(data)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Top Experience', description='Top experience all time including others not in this server', color=0xff5555)
    embed.add_field(name='**1st Place**', value=leaderboard[0], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='**2nd Place**', value=leaderboard[1], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='**3rd Place**', value=leaderboard[2], inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you want to experience only in the server that the command was called in:

```py
@client.command
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    leaderboard1 = get_top_experience(data)
    leaderboard = leaderboard1.copy()
    for i, user in enumerate(leaderboard1):
        if ctx.guild.get_member(user.user) is None:
            del leaderboard[i]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Top Experience', description='Top experience all time in this server', color=0xff5555)
    embed.add_field(name='**1st Place**', value=leaderboard[0], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='**2nd Place**', value=leaderboard[1], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='**3rd Place**', value=leaderboard[2], inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```